# Desktop launcher icons

Tags: launcher, icons

I have created a few launcher icons on my desktop using `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop`. When I start the apps an icon appears in the launcher bar, but some are the icons associated with the application and some are (I assume) the icon associated with gnome desktop (a spring platform). Each app is consistent in its behaviour.

The apps seem to run normally regardless of the icon displayed, but I would prefer to see the right one. Can anyone tell me what I need to do differently?

I'm running 16.04 on an Asus laptop - thanks.